# Click a option list to scrape data using Scrapy (Python)

Tags: javascript, python, web-scraping, scrapy, scrapy-splash

Here is the link of page I am trying to scrape data from. There is a option list which changes the data below on click of an option which is needed to be scraped.

https://www.qgold.com/Series/106060

I am using scrapy-splash and tired different solution mostly with splash mouse_click but none worked. Most of the solutions are on click of a button but here I have a list. So I am not sure how capture the option in list to use splash mouse click.

Here is the picture of option list I need to click on:

[image: Here is the picture of option list I need to click on]

Comment: Could you provide the attempted code and a screenshot of the exact part of the website you're trying to scrape?

Comment: @Jacques I have attacked the screenshot of the part of website I need to click on.

Comment: every option has unique `value="..."` which you could use to select this object and click.. You could also get all options as list and later use `[0]` (etc.) to select element on list and click it.

Comment: @furas could please share a sample code for this

Comment: https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/dynamic-content.html

Answer (score 0):

Found something that might help you a bit atleast. First you inspect the page in chrome click on the Network tab. Then click on of the filter buttons on the page.

You'll see that a POST request is sent to `https://www.qgold.com/ProductDetail/GetProductPlus` with the form-data: `style: 10K5RR-18`. So 10K5RR is some kind of identifier for that subproduct.

That request get a response with all details for that subproduct